# large json argument in webapi odata

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, odata

I got a WebApi OData service where I need an action to take an arbitrary json parameter.

Is there a way to have something like a JObject as an OData action parameter?
`action.Parameter<JObject>()` does not work.

> The complex type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer' has a reference to itself through the property 'Parent'. A recursive loop of complex types is not allowed.

It works using a string argument but it means an unnecessary conversion in both ends for all requests. The json might also be large (100kb+) so I assume it puts pressure on the Large Object Heap to use strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OData services are normally strongly-typed, so you'll have to go out of your way to overcome Web API's built-in mapping from JSON to CLR types.

First, define a new media type formatter that reads JTokens. Note the custom media type in use.

```
public class RawJsonMediaTypeFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
{
    private static readonly MediaTypeHeaderValue _customMediaType = 
        MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/prs.adrianm+json");

    public RawJsonMediaTypeFormatter() : base()
    {
        this.Intialize();
    }

    protected RawJsonMediaTypeFormatter(MediaTypeFormatter formatter) : base(formatter)
    {
        this.Intialize();
    }

    protected void Intialize()
    {
        this.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(_customMediaType);
    }

    public override MediaTypeFormatter GetPerRequestFormatterInstance(Type type, HttpRequestMessage request, MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType)
    {
        if (type == typeof(JToken) && mediaType.MediaType == _customMediaType.MediaType)
        {
            return this;
        }

        return base.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance(type, request, mediaType);
    }

    public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        return type == typeof(JToken);
    }

    public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public override Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
    {
        return this.ReadFromStreamAsync(type, readStream, content, formatterLogger, default(CancellationToken));
    }

    public override Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        object result;

        using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(readStream)))
        {
            result = JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
}
```

As part of Web API registration, add an instance of the custom formatter to the HttpConfiguration and declare your OData action. Note that the type of the action parameter is vanilla `object`.

```
        config.Formatters.Clear();
        config.Formatters.AddRange(ODataMediaTypeFormatters.Create());
        config.Formatters.Add(new RawJsonMediaTypeFormatter());

        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        var arbitraryJsonAction = builder.Action("ArbitraryJson");
        arbitraryJsonAction.Parameter<object>("json");
        arbitraryJsonAction.Returns<string>();
```

Add a controller method for the action.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ODataRoute("ArbitraryJson")]
    public IHttpActionResult ArbitraryJson(JToken json)
    {
        return this.Ok(json.ToString());
    }
```

On the client, remember to set `Content-Type` to the custom media type handled by the custom formatter:

```
POST http://host/ArbitraryJson
Content-Type: application/prs.adrianm+json

[1, 2, {"foo": true }]
```

The response payload should look something like the following:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "http://host/$metadata#Edm.String",
  "value": "[\r\n  1,\r\n  2,\r\n  {\r\n    \"foo\": true\r\n  }\r\n]"
}
```

Comment: Very nice answer. Wish I could upvote more for your effort. The need for a different content type is probably a deal-breaker in my situation but I definetely learned a lot from your post. Thanks.

Comment: You could try using `application/json` with extra parameters. For example, `application/json;format=raw`.